# Drupal 6 - Build Menu "...not available at this time." Issue

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, nodes

I was just recently given administrative rights to the Drupal account to our firm to do some front-end work. I need to revamp a lot of the structure and content, however I do not see the 'Menus' option under 'Site building', more so I cannot access it via URL with I type `"http://mysite.com/admin/build/menu"`. I get the following 404 Message "This content is not available at this time." My DBA says that it used to be accessible for he gave me an account. My question is what did he or I do wrong? I edited some of the Input Type Profiles and used the Rebuild Permissions option several times but have had no luck. I have not be able to find much mention of this through research. Is this a common scenario?

**Full HTML prefs:**
[image]

**WYSIWYG Configs:**
**[image: Screenshot of Filters Config:]**

**Type Settings Per User:**
[image]

**Filters for Filtered HTML:**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are saying **../admin/build/menu** , I assume that you are using Drupal6.

Step 1: Navigate to `example.com/admin/user/permissions`

Step 2: Search for **menu module** and give permission for your **user roles** as required.

Comment: I'm actually getting the same 403 message "This content is not available at this time." when going to `mysite.com/admin/user/permissions` as well. I was told my account had full capabilities. So will have to meet with the DBA again or is there something I can do about the permissions myself? Thanks.

Comment: that means you don't have permission for viewing the `menu contents` , tell the owner of the site to grant the permission

Comment: Okay thanks, that's what I told them yesterday. I just wanted to double check before I ask again. It's not been very well maintained over the past 4 years. Thanks again.

Comment: it is clearly a permission issue. mark it as `Answered` if it solves your problem.

Comment: are you sure about this though and that it is not something to do with the Post Settings / `Rebuild Permissions` button? I am confused as to why my DBA was able to see the `menu contents` via my account after he just added it.

Comment: try granting the `permission` of `menu module` to your `user role` and check.

Comment: I added a number of screenshots to my question in hopes that I could get an extended answer. Does any of this look incorrect to you?

Comment: err..you told `/admin/build/menu` page shows 404 error,

please check the `example.com/admin/user/permissions` for permissions

Comment: `admin/build/menu` was actually 403 Error. When I go to `admin/user/permissions` I also get 403 Error. It says, "You do not have any administrative items."

Comment: yes that is what I told, you don't have permission to view the pages, tell your site-owner to grant you permission.